# ggplot2: Full plot size image

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggimage

I wonder how to get ggplot2 graph with full plot size image

```
library("ggplot2")
library("ggimage")
set.seed(12345)
df1 <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1),
                y = rnorm(1),
                image = "https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.png")

ggplot(df1, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_image(aes(image=image), size=.05)
```

[image]

```
df2 <- data.frame()
ggplot(df2) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with full plot size image?

Comment: Thanks @ScipioneSarlo for your interest in my problem. I want to get a plot with image where image should cover the whole plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library("ggimage")
set.seed(12345)
df1 <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1),
                  y = rnorm(1),
                  image = "https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.png")

ggplot(df1, aes(x, y)) + 
    geom_image(aes(image=image), size=1)
```

[image]